# How to enable persistence in helm prometheus-operator

Tags: kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, prometheus-operator

I am using the `prometheus-operator` helm chart. I want the data in prometheus server to persist. But open restart of the `prometheus` `StatefulSet`, the data disappears. When inspecting the `yaml` definitions of the associated `StatefulSet` and `Pod` objects, there is no `PersistVolumeClaim`.

I tried the following change to `values.yaml`, per the docs in https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus:

```
prometheus:
  server:
    persistentVolume:
      enabled: true
```

but this has no effect on the end result (even after reinstalling the chart and reinstalling the `StatefulSet`).

I expect the `StatefulSet` backing the prometheus server to have persistent volume claims, so that data is persisted upon restart.

Comment: According to the docs server.persistentVolume.enabled=true by default. How do you installing the prometheus?

Comment: Prometheus is presumably installed as part of the `stable/prometheus-operator` helm chart, as I never install it independently. I cannot follow the `stable/prometheus-operator` chart source code well enough to understand exactly where this happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By adding a `prometheus.prometheusSpec.storageSpec` to `values.yaml`, the PersistentVolumeClaim was successfully attached to the Prometheus server:

```
prometheus:
  server:
    persistentVolume:
      enabled: true
  prometheusSpec:
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: its working fine how to create persistentVolume for grafan in prometheus-operator.

Comment: as of march 2023, the part `server:persistentVolume:enabled: true` is not necessary

Answer (score 10):

With latest Helm Chart this worked for me:
(I'm using AWS)

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          storageClassName: gp2
          accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10Gi
```