# How to enable persistence in prometheus-community chart?

Tags: kubernetes, persistence, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set up persistent storage with the new [prometheus-community](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus) helm chart. I have modified the helm *values* files as seen below. Currently when the chart is reinstalled (I use [Tiltfiles](https://docs.tilt.dev/api.html) for this) the PVC is deleted and therefore the data is not persisted.
I assume that the problem could have something to do with the fact that there is no statefulset running for the server, but I am not sure how to fix it.

(The solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391693/how-to-enable-persistence-in-helm-prometheus-operator) does not solve my problem, as it is for the old chart.)

```
server:
  persistentVolume:
    enabled: true
    storageClass: default
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    size: 8Gi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enabled the statefulset on the prometheus server and now it seems to work.

```
server:
  persistentVolume:
    enabled: true
    storageClass: default-hdd-retain
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    size: 40Gi
  statefulSet:
    enabled: true
```